# Cocos2d 2.1 with CCLayerPanZoom : _scheduler not found

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cclayerpanzoom

I started upgrading cocos2d sdk from Cocos2d 2.0 to Cocos2d 2.1 (COCOS2D_VERSION 0x00020100)

For CCLayerPanZoom it is showing error. I just took new CCLayerPanZoom and still same error

Here is screenshot:

[image]

If I add new member variable in .h and assign it in .m then error goes..Is that wrong way? what's best solution?

Comment: did you get the latest develop branch version of cocos2d-iphone-extensions? This one: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone-extensions/tree/develop-v2  ... the "master" branch is outdated

Comment: thanks a lot for this link... no error in this new version.